# Limit page news feed to grab JUST page's posts

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm using the facebook graph api to grab the news feed off a page using /username/feed?limit=20 -- is there an argument like the limit to just get their posts instead of including posts from fans?

Currently, I am able to call with this:

```
require_once "facebook.php";
$facebook = new Facebook(array('appId' => 'xxx','secret' => 'xxx'));
$fbstatus = $facebook->api('/pagename/feed?limit=20');
```

but it shows all of the page's posts including fans

Comment: I ended up just doing it a weak sluggish way.. but it works..

        foreach ($fbstatus[data] as $wall_post) {
          if ($wall_post[from][name] == "username") {
          // Exected Code
          }

I wish the query was just returning the proper posts though..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite understand. You first need to make sure you have an access token generated for the very site you want to read. Instead of reading the feed which returns all activity including especially the sharing activities you need to call "statuses" referring to the facebook documentation. The feed always includes public posts by fans made to the page. I therefore assume your problem is to define exactely what data you want to show.

Comment: to generate an access token, I have to prompt the user for permission right? I don't want to do that. The above code works because I am getting a public feed, but the /statuses requires a token, in which I don't want to have to acquire

Comment: Ahhh, yes, I see. I thought you are planning to pull your own statuses and therefore would be the owner of the site. In that case you would have to ask only your account for permission and verify the access token once (and of course) grant the referring app offline_access in the backend to make the fetch possible even when your account in not conected to facebook.

Comment: No prob, mate. I am new to this myself. On www.bordemundo.com I integrated some examples, it's my playdo for facebook integration. In the header I fetch the circle pic from our groups current profile pic, some other stuff includes the fetch of our facebook photo albums to display them and much more. Have a look and feel free to grab the code there. Make sure to look out for sections you might want to choose as the app ids and stuff. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Try `https://graph.facebook.com/{user_id}/posts`

That will give you the posts of that page instead of all the posts in their feed from all users.

Answer (score 0):

With the Graph API just call `/pageid/statuses?limit=20&access_token={ValidPageAccessToken}`

Comment: Not quite what I am looking for, I don't want to get permissions from any users. Currently, I am able to call with this:

require_once "facebook.php"; 
$facebook = new Facebook(array('appId' => 'xxx','secret' => 'xxx'));
$fbstatus = $facebook->api('/pagename/feed?limit=20');

but it shows all of the page's posts including fans

Comment: Edited my response to be for pages and not a user